# Ошибка при чтение данных из Excel (С#)

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

Если в excel-файле существуют пустые строки, то выдается ошибка

> Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "int.Parse(string)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов.

Свойство:

```
class Price
    {
        public double Num { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Код:

```
Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application(); 
Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open($"{filepath}"); 
Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[2]; 
var lastCell = ObjWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);

for (int i = 1; i < lastCell.Row; i++) 
    for (int j = 1; j < lastCell.Column; j++)
    Magazine.Add(new DataPrice{ 
         Num = double .Parse(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j++].Text),
         Price = double .Parse(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Text)
    });

ObjWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
ObjWorkExcel.Quit();
GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
var cells = ObjWorkSheet.Cells;

for (int i = 2; i < lastCell.Row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < lastCell.Column; j++)
    {
        string num = cells[i, j++].Text;
        string price = cells[i, j].Text;

        Magazine.Add(new DataPrice
        {
            Num = string.IsNullOrEmpty(num) ? 0 : double.Parse(num),
            Price = string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? 0 : double.Parse(price)
        });
    }
}
```

Ещё более правильный вариант от @aepot, с использованием `TryParse`, который защитит не только от пустых строк, но и от значений, не являющихся валидными числами `double`.

```
var cells = ObjWorkSheet.Cells;

for (int i = 2; i < lastCell.Row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < lastCell.Column; j++)
    {
        Magazine.Add(new DataPrice
        {
            Num = double.TryParse(cells[i, j++].Text, out double num) ? num : 0,
            Price = double.TryParse(cells[i, j].Text, out double price) ? price : 0
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Так как решения аналогичные, просто одно более эффективно, второе менее, я бы оставил одно. Меня упоминать не обязательно :)

Comment: Спасибо, все работает :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < lastCell.Row; i++) 
    for (int j = 1; j < lastCell.Column; j++)
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Text))
    Magazine.Add(new DataPrice{ 
         Num = double.Parse(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j++].Text),
         Price = double.Parse(ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Text)
    });
```